# Is it possible to run this github repo on my local system?

Tags: express, github, local

Im trying to run this github repo on my local system
https://github.com/NKShukla/IIITD_Sports_Management_System

But when I do 'npm run start' it just freezes
I have installed all the required dependencies

Comment: could be hanging on connection to mysql due to ingress setting on aws, freezes is not much to go on, do some debugging

Answer (score -1):

it's actually didn't freeze. just go to http://localhost:8080 in your browser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).